# Alignment of item text in a tkinter listbox

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to align text within a tkinter listbox. I have 3 words in a string and want them to be aligned in such a way, that there is equal distance between these words. So every word in every row has to start at the same position than the word in the row before / afterwards. Using .format and print do the job pretty well. For example:

```
var1 = "balbla"
var2 = "car"
var3 = 10
var4 = "bla"
var5 = "highway"
var6 = 30
all1 = '{:20s} {:20s} {:20s}'.format(var1, var2, str(var3))
all2 = '{:20s} {:20s} {:20s}'.format(var4, var5, str(var6))
print(all1)
print(all2)
```

However, when I add all1 and all2 as items of listbox using "insert", the words are not aligned anymore. Why's that and how can I align the text used for the items of listbox?

Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to assign a monospace font to the listbox if you are trying to align items by using whitespace for padding.

Comment: Thank you, that was the problem. Now it works as expected.